Why do fixed-iteration register decrement loops exhibit jitter even without interrupts or frequency changes？
I aimed to understand the characteristics of hardware counters (e.g., Intel x86's rdtsc) by testing a piece of code with a fixed execution time. The test code uses a fixed number of register decrements, as follows.
unsigned long long cycles = 3600000000UL*duration;  // CPU base freq. is 3.6GHz

tsc_start = tsc_now();
__asm__ __volatile__ (
        "mov %[cycles], %%rcx\n\t"
        "delay_loop:  dec %%rcx\n\t"
        "jnz delay_loop\n\t"
        : 
        : [cycles] "r" (cycles)
        : "rcx"
        );
tsc_end = tsc_now();

To reduce interference, the program runs on a CPU core with interrupts and task scheduling removed. This CPU operates at its base frequency and is the only running task of the NUMA node.
The relationship between the number of loop iterations (duration) and the measured clock cycles is shown below. The jitters are no more than a few hundred clock cycles (first two columns), and IMHO, they come from the cold start of the first few iterations (predictive branching and memory subsystem).



duration (seconds)
cycles used
sleep
dd




1
3600000070




10
36000000334
36000061476
36000114526


100
360000000032
360000083336
360000121658



In comparative experiments, interference programs were executed on another CPU within the same NUMA node as follows:

sleep : for i in {1..1000}; do (taskset -c $core sleep $((RANDOM % 10 + 1))&); done

dd : while true; do taskset -c 12 dd if=/dev/zero of=bigfile bs=10240000 count=100; done


Even without interrupts or task scheduling, the execution time of the test code was significantly impacted by the interference programs. The test code exhibited substantial jitter, with execution delays of over 121K cycles in the worst-case scenario.
Why is this the case? The test program did not access memory during its iteration loop, so it should not have been impacted by other tasks.
Enviroments
To run the test program on the CPU exclusively, achieving 1 iteration per CPU cycle, I have configured my system (Intel 2nd Gen Scalable CPU x2) as follow(As much as I can remember):

BIOS Configuration: Disabled Hyper-Threading, turned off Turbo Boost, and disabled related power management settings.

Linux Kernel Boot Parameters: Configured to isolate CPUs on a dedicated NUMA node using nohz_full, and disabled watchdog and Machine Check Exception (MCE) with parameters nowatchdog and mce=off.

System Configuration: Disabled real-time threshold by setting echo -1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sched_rt_runtime_us, and enabled user-space to use instruction rdpmc by setting echo 2 > /sys/bus/event_source/devices/cpu/rdpmc .

Application Configuration: The test program runs with SCHED_FIFO priority, fixed on a CPU of the isolated NUMA node, and performance counters are read before and after the test code using rdpmc to measure performance counter values (total instructions, number of interrupts). Interrupts can also be disabled and re-enabled using cli and sti instructions (if using a Linux kernel version prior to 5.4).


Cache-related Implementations
I designed an implementation as shown in the figure. An individual noise process runs at a different CPU and repeatedly accesses the same pre-allocated memory segment (for about 2-6 seconds), while the test process runs.

The memory segment size of the noise process differs with each iteration.
Regarding the memory size: jitter starts to appear when the memory size is around the size of the L3 cache (33MB), and it increases as the cache size grows.

This easily suggests that some mechanisms, such as L3 cache replacement, hardware prefetching, or something similar to DDIO might have replaced the L2/L3 cache, causing the L1i where the execution instructions reside to be evicted. However, as Peter Cordes mentions, L2/L3 caches of the test CPU model are not inclusive, which is puzzling.
Additionally, the test program’s execution code is so short that it should only span a few cache lines. Jitter should occur only when specific cache ways are accessed.
Other Observations:

Similar issues have been observed on other CPU architectures.

Interfering programs running on other NUMA nodes do not contribute to jitter, and not all programs running on other CPUs within the same NUMA node contribute to jitter.

Interfering programs, even if not entering the kernel, can still contribute to jitter.


Minimal working example of the test code

What CPU model number are you using?  Does the memory-intensive program perhaps use 256-bit or 512-bit SIMD instructions, which could maybe(?) force a CPU voltage transition even at base frequency?  SIMD instructions lowering CPU frequency shows a Xeon Gold 5120 needs to turbo to run at its non-SIMD base frequency.

34k cycles is about right for a frequency (or just voltage) transition: Lost Cycles on Intel? An inconsistency between rdtsc and CPU_CLK_UNHALTED.REF_TSC - you could use perf stat and/or rdpmc to verify that the core clock was halted for most of the extra reference cycles, not e.g. running some SMM interrupt (which you'd expect to be independent of code running on another core.)

Assuming you're on Linux, is perf stat able to profile your program and verify that there were no kernel instructions executed on that core?  Like an IPMI handler for a TLB shootdown?  But I'd hope that would only happen on cores where a thread of another process had recently executed.   I guess ideally with -a --per-core to also detect context-switches away from your task, e.g. for RCU run_on each core.  Or just perf stat -e context_switches,... might detect that.


The perf sampling process interrupts my test code; 2) The INST_RETIRED.ANY counter obtained via rdpmc matches the loop iteration count in the test code, and the CPU_CLK_UNHALTED.THREAD counter is consistent with CPU_CLK_UNHALTED.REF_TSC and the time reported by rdtsc; 3) I am confident that the test code is continuously occupying the CPU, without being interrupted or context-switched (this is verified by the number of clock cycles executed, hardware counters, and some statistics from /proc).



It doesn't seem like the CPU frequency is changing. I've read some articles about frequency scaling, and this process typically takes tens of microseconds, which seems larger than the jitter I observe. Furthermore, I can reduce the jitter by decreasing the execution time of the test program. BTW, the environment consists of a server with two Intel Xeon Gold 6256 CPUs, each with a base frequency of 3.6GHz. SMI can be monitored using rdmsr 0x34, and it does not occur during the execution of the test code.


It doesn't seem like the CPU frequency is changing - Yeah, that would be very unlikely to produce counts that were still so close to 1 iter/cycle.  I suggested a voltage change at the same frequency if a core was executing 256-bit SIMD instructions.  But CPU_CLK_UNHALTED.REF_TSC matching rdtsc rules out halting of the clock.  (Which on the linked Q&A lasted 8.5us on a Skyale laptop).  And counts for non-ref core clock also matching confirms the core frequency was 3.6GHz, too. Thanks for checking and ruling out my guesses; some of them were pretty unlikely anyway, but good to be sure :)

Can you include more info on your test harness? Say, how do you disable scheduling and interrupt on a CPU thread and how do you collect metrics? So we can: a) exclude possible side effects/quirks/cornercases; b) see if we can reproduce the results. Also, if you run other types of workload on the interference program, do the jitter still happen?

Do you have a [mcve] of an interfering program that does cause jitter?  And one that doesn't?  Unlikely guesses, but things that have system-wide effects on other cores include cache-line-split locked atomic RMWs, and wbinvd (fairly implausible; it's privileged and I don't think the kernel would ever use it).  I'm not sure split locks would bother the uop-cache of your test thread, though, and it's unlikely that a normally-compiled program would have any misaligned atomic RMWs.

The register decrement iteration as the test code does not cause jitter, but memory allocation and access can contribute significantly to jitter. If you're concerned about cache-line sharing issues, I've attempted to use SMC to align the test code with a hugetlb page to avoid potential TLB and i-cache misalignment problems. However, I am still unsure whether TSC calibration is involved—does the OS kernel perform TSC clock calibration across NUMA nodes?

You should provide a self-contained example that we can run.

That's said, it is interesting that the jitter amount does not go up in proportion to duration. This sort of indicates it is mostly an edge effect, I.e. related to the start/stop timing, more than an effect that happens continually while the benchmark is running.

I have added a runnable example of the test code, but I apologize as I cannot provide access to a live real-time running environment. The cli and sti instructions in it may not be compatible with higher kernel versions.

The version you linked on Godbolt is compiled without optimization.  Is that how you really build your test, with all those stores/reloads temporaries involved in the rdtsc calculation?  Store-forwarding still works even on cache-miss, so I don't think other cores evicting our stack from cache can explain your results, but it's weird.  (Your Xeon doesn't have an inclusive L3 like client chips and earlier xeons, though, so L3 eviction won't force eviction from L2/L1d.)

Compiling with optimization disabled is adding memory operations inside the timed region, but none after the loop before the final RDTSCP where they wouldn't have time to retire on their own before RDTSCP drains the ROB (Reorder Buffer).

When sharing the code, I didn't realize that the compilation options might affect the memory access pattern of the program. I added the -O2 in my test environment, and I noticed that there were no memory access operations inside the timed region (between the rdtsc instructions) in the generated assembly. I have updated the Godbolt link.

You have it backwards: I said your Xeon Scalable's L3 cache is not inclusive.  So lines can be evicted from L3 while still hot in L2 and/or L1i in a core like they would be on a "client" CPU like my desktop Skylake.  But there is a different set of tags (without storage for data) used to keep track of which core has copies of a line (shared or M/E), and evicting a line from that would I think have the same effect, of sending an invalidate.  That might be what's going on.

Maybe once your memory-access "noise" has been going for a while, evictions in the coherence-directory tags settles down, and that might explain @BeeOnRope's observation that the jitter doesn't seem to grow linearly with how long the timed region's run time overlap with the noise load.  Have you tried starting the noise load well ahead of the microbenchmark, and having it do a warm-up run to get the cache line containing the rdtscp + loop instructions hot in cache?  (Make sure the compiler isn't duplicating the machine code instead of looping back to it; that would defeat the warm-up.)

"To be not, or not to be not, that is my writing problem."  Are you concerned that the microbenchmark program doesn't have cache line alignment and shares cache lines with other cores, which could cause cache invalidation due to those cache lines being modified on other cores? To avoid this, both my microbenchmark instructions and the memory segment accessed by the noise program are located on hugetlb 1GB pages, which means their memory is always physically contiguous and cache line aligned.

The indexing function used by L3 is a hash of all address bits above the 6-bit offset-within-line, unlike how L1 and L2 caches use a few contiguous bits between that and the tag bits.  Using different areas of a 1G hugepage (or of different 1G hugepages) doesn't guarantee lack of aliasing in L3.  The coherence directory in Xeon Scalable might be similarly indexed.
